# What is a Style Guide and How to Create a Web Style Guide?

Tags: css

What is a Style Guide and How to Create a Web Style Guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Style Guide** is a document that sets standard coding practices. There are often a number of ways to accomplish the same thing when coding, and a **style guide** is there to define the best / preferred way to do it.

This can include how comments are formatted, how to handle indentations (**tabs** vs **spaces**), whether to use hexadecimal (**#000**) or rgba (**0,0,0,1**) for color values, and a number of other things. Below are three examples.

---

**Comments Example**:

```
// This is a comment.
```

or

```
/* This is a comment */
```

---

**CSS Structure Example**

```
#example{color:white;}
```

or

```
#example {
  color: white;
}
```

---

**Color Value Example**

```
color: #000000;
```

or

```
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
```